# Probability of No Collision

Tags: probability

Four Athletes are standing at the vertices of a square park.When a whistle is blown, each of the athletes starts running along the side of the park at a speed of 20 Km/hr.The probability that they do no collide with each other is?

I am completely blank at this.

Please provide a clue to solve this.

Comment: If they all run clockwise or counterclockwise, they'll never collide.

Comment: And Each one can do so independently with a probability of $\frac{1}{2}$ right?

Comment: It's not explicitly stated in the question, but I suppose that is indeed what you have to assume.

Comment: I think $\frac{1}{2}$ is suitable because only two directions are possible and an athlete can choose only one at a time right?

Comment: The athlete could decide to prefer one direction over another, or he could decide to choose a direction with probability $p\neq\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the probability, we need to make an assumption about which direction each athlete runs. Let's assume, as you suggest, that

> Each one can [run clockwise or counterclockwise] independently with a probability of $\frac12$.

Now that this assumption is added to the problem, there are 16 possbilities: each of the four athletes can run *Clockwise* or *Counterclockwise*, and all $16$ possibilities are equally likely.

If one athlete runs *Clockwise* and another runs *Counterclockwise* then the two athletes will collide (convince yourself of this if it isn't clear).

So the only possibilities where the athletes do not collide are two:

1. *Clockwise, Clockwise, Clockwise, Clockwise*
2. *Counterclockwise, Counterclockwise, Counterclockwise, Counterclockwise*

That's $2$ out of $16$ equally-likely possibilities; therefore, the probability is $\frac{2}{16} = \frac{1}{8}$.